# Build Lucene Synonyms

Tags: lucene, synonym

I've the following code

```
static class TaggerAnalyzer extends Analyzer {

    @Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String s, Reader reader) {

        SynonymMap.Builder builder = new SynonymMap.Builder(true);
        builder.add(new CharsRef("al"), new CharsRef("americanleague"), true);
        builder.add(new CharsRef("al"), new CharsRef("a.l."), true);
        builder.add(new CharsRef("nba"), new CharsRef("national" + SynonymMap.WORD_SEPARATOR + "basketball" + SynonymMap.WORD_SEPARATOR + "association"), true);

        SynonymMap mySynonymMap = null;
        try {
            mySynonymMap = builder.build();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Tokenizer source = new ClassicTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_40, reader);
        TokenStream filter = new StandardFilter(Version.LUCENE_40, source);
        filter = new LowerCaseFilter(Version.LUCENE_40, filter);
        filter = new SynonymFilter(filter, mySynonymMap, true);
        return new TokenStreamComponents(source, filter);
    }
}
```

And I'm running some test, so far, everything went ok until I figured out this scenario.

```
    String title = "Very short title at a.l. bla bla"

    Assert.assertTrue(TagUtil.evaluate(memoryIndex,"americanleague"));
    Assert.assertTrue(TagUtil.evaluate(memoryIndex,"al"));
```

I was expecting that both cases ran successfully, but americanleague didn't match with "a.l." besides both "a.l." and "americanleague" are "al" synonyms.

So, what do I do? I don't want to add all combinations to the Map. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have your arguments to `builder.add` backwards.  Try:

```
builder.add(new CharsRef("americanleague"), new CharsRef("al"), true);
builder.add(new CharsRef("a.l."), new CharsRef("al"), true);
builder.add(new CharsRef("national" + SynonymMap.WORD_SEPARATOR + "basketball" + SynonymMap.WORD_SEPARATOR + "association"), new CharsRef("nba"), true);
```

The `SynonymFilter` just maps from the first arg (input) to the second arg (output), rather than the other way around.  So you have rules to translate "al" to two different synonyms, but none that do anything to inputs of "a.l." or "americanleague".

Comment: Yes, but what would happen if I have 5 words that should work as synonyms? how many mappings do I need in the builder?

Comment: I would say 4 or 5.  You would want a mapping from each of the synonyms to some common word that will represent any of them in the index.  In the case you've given, you would map "americanleague" -> "al", and "a.l." -> "al", so you have three synonyms with two rules.  As long as you apply the SynonymFilter when querying as well as when indexing, there isn't any need to try to enumerate all possible combinations.

Comment: According to my tests, also I need to map both sides. al -> a.l. and a.l. -> al. Besides, the transitivity you mention doesn't work for me either. With 3 words, I need to map at least a1-a2, a2-a1, a1-a3, a3-a1, a2-a3, a3-a2

Comment: Sounds like you aren't applying the same analyzer at query and index time.  How I would normally use a SynonymFilter would be to generate a one-way mapping as indicated, set `keepOrig` to false, and apply it when indexing documents, and when running a query, such that terms "americanleague" and "a.l." would never appear in post-analysis form of either a document (except the *stored* data, of course) or a query.