# Lucene: TokenFilter to replace chars and produce new tokens as synonyms

Tags: lucene

I want to map chars like this:

```
private static final Map<String, String> MAP = Map.of("CH", "X",
                                                      "X", "CH",
                                                      "I", "Y",
                                                      "Y", "I",
                                                      "S", "Z",
                                                      "Z", "S",
                                                      "F", "PH",
                                                      "PH", "F");
```

So for ex, XANTION is tokenized to CHANTION, PHYTOVEIN is tokenized to FITOVEIN, keeping original tokens.

Those are medicine names, it would generate "synonyms" for those, to use when analyzing search terms.

Could I use any existing token filter?

Comment: Do the [SynonymFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_8_2/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/synonym/SynonymFilter.html) and [SynonymMap](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_8_2/analyzers-common/index.html) meet your needs? Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22078669/build-lucene-synonyms).

Comment: Or maybe I misunderstood - and you are looking for something more like a _prefix_ synonym handler? And you do not have the full list of synonym _words_ up-front?

Comment: I want a token filter to take one token and generate the alternatives replacing the letters. I looked on the implementations on Lucene, seems it does not exists. Trying to implement my own.

Comment: Sorry for the initial misunderstanding. Agree with you - I can't think of a suitable built-in approach for this.